# Is there a way to import Illustrator vectors as shapes in Keynote

Tags: macos, keynote, color

As the title states: Is there a way to import Adobe Illustrator vectors into the shape library in Keynote? I'd like to import shapes and be able to change its color and resize it within keynote.

Comment: Do you have Illustrator (or any other app capable of reading .ai files and exporting .svg files – like Sketch or Affinity Designer) at hand? It's totally doable, but a pretty convoluted process.

Comment: Yes, I've got the entire Adobe suite!

Comment: Great. Which CC version?

Comment: The newest. Illustrator is at version 23.1.1 right now.